# ADB shell input keypress play/pause doesn't work in Netflix/Hulu Android apps?

Tags: adb, 6.0-marshmallow, shell, input-methods, media-button

I'm trying to control my Android Box (running Android 6.0, my guess is a modified version of a phone's os, definitely not the official android tv os) via adb for a home automation project & I'm having a bit of trouble with some apps not responding to emulated `keypress` events. So far I've experienced the following results:

#### Apps used for testing

**Xfinity Stream** - Pause & Play both work (using `adb shell input 85`, MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE keycode)
**Hulu** - Pause works & Play doesn't (again using `adb shell input 85`)
**Netflix** - Both Pause & Play don't work (tried both `adb shell input 85` & `adb shell input 127/126`, PAUSE & PLAY keycodes)

Has anyone else experienced this issue of inconsistency with apps responding to keypresses? Is there any way I can reliably simulate the Play/Pause for all apps?

System-wide the Power & Mute/Unmute work, so I'm curious why the Play/Pause doesn't.